# Bag of words for binary descriptors

Tags: computer-vision, sift, descriptor, orb, feature-descriptor

In the classic bag of words paradigm for image descriptors we:

1. Define the set of descriptors for each image
2. We lunch k-means on the set of all the descriptors of all the images
3. As result, each descriptor is assigned to a cluter
4. We define the "visual word" (or in other words, how to represent an image through a vector): for each image, we define the `i-th` dimension of our "visual word" vector as the number of descriptors belonging to the `i-th` cluster.
5. We have obtained a `k-dimension` "visual word" vector representing our image.

This approach is perfect for complicate and expensive SIFT descriptors...But is the same for binaries and fast descriptors (like BRIEF, ORB, BRISK or FREAK)?

According to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619039/Bag-of-Features-Descriptor-on-SIFT-Features-with-O) there is no difference, but I wonder if the expensive `k-means` algorithm can be efficiently computed in binary space (or if there is a better clustering algorithm) or if there is an alternative approach for bag of word model with binary vectors.